# How do you display your own error messages with laravel-jsvalidation?

Tags: php, laravel, message, laravel-validation, jsvalidation

I would like to figure out how to create your own error messages for your rules (e.g. regular expression rules) to be reused by both server PHP and client javascript (using [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org) through [laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) )

I have tried and can not make it work, and below is a small example to show what I am trying to do but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

My small example:

In the file "routes\web.php":

```
    Route::get('/minimal_example_laravel_jsvalidation', function() {
        // Of course these rules should not really be defined here since 
        // the purpose of the rules is to also reuse them from PHP Laravel code
        // but my problem is now how to generate javascript that can 
        // reuse the same rules and therefore I just put the rules and messages
        // here in this minimalistic example illustrating the problem
        $rules = [
            'three_digits' => 'required|regex:/^\d{3}$/'
        ];    
        $messages = [
            'three_digits' => 'Must be exactly three digits'
        ];
        $validator = JsValidator::make($rules, $messages);
        return view('minimal_example_laravel_jsvalidation')->with("validator", $validator);
    });
```

In the file "resources\views\minimal_example_laravel_jsvalidation.blade.php":

```
...
{!! $validator->selector('#myForm') !!}
...
```

When using the URL 
http://localhost:8000/minimal_example_laravel_jsvalidation
with the web browser and then "view source" I can see that the following javascript code has been generated by the above "$validator->selector" :

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myForm").each(function() {
            $(this).validate({
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'invalid-feedback',

                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.parent('.input-group').length ||
                        element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                        // else just place the validation message immediately after the input
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid'); // add the Bootstrap error class to the control group
                },



                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
                },

                success: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid'); // remove the Boostrap error class from the control group
                },

                focusInvalid: true,

                rules: {"three_digits":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"The three digits field is required.",true],["Regex",["\/^\\d{3}$\/"],"The three digits format is invalid.",false]]}}            });
        });
    });
```

Indeed, the error message I get when not writing three digits in the field through my web browser, is as above "The three digits format is invalid." while I expect that it instead should be "Must be exactly three digits" as I defined in the "$messages" array.

I have seen that it is possible with Laravel to create PHP classes with "Custom Validation Rules" where you also can define custom messages, but as far as I understand, if you use those custom rules with laravel-jsvalidation then the validation must be done with AJAX instead of javascript validation directly within the browser, which is what I want to do instead of doing AJAX calls.

I am using these versions:

laravel/framework v7.4.0

proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation 3.0.0

Comment: Why are you using packages instead of using CDN of jquery validate plugin. Its so easy to use.

Comment: Because I want to avoid duplication of validation rules which is also the purpose of laravel-jsvalidation.

https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing messages array like this,

```
$messages = [
     'three_digits.required' => 'Three Digits field is required',
     'three_digits.regex' => 'Must be exactly three digits'
];
```

Note I have added rule also to the message key. (`'three_digits.required'`)